# Angular - splice function always removes last element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an array of objects that I want to remove certain objects when a Delete key is clicked. However, it always removes the last item from the rows array, no matter how many rows I have created. Even if I explicitly put in a line like so, $scope.rows.splice(1,1) - it will still remove the last element, not the second.

JS

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .directive('queryBuilder', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.rows = [{}]

        $scope.$on('addRowRqst', function(evt) {
          // evt.stopPropagation()
          $scope.rows.push({})
        });
        $scope.$on('removeRowRqst', function(evt, args) {
          // evt.stopPropagation()
          //THIS IS WHERE THE REMOVE HAPPENS 
          $scope.rows.splice($scope.rows.indexOf(args),1);
        });        
      },
      templateUrl: 'queryBuilderTemplate.html',
    }
  }).directive('queryRow', function() {
    return {
      scope: {},
      restrict: 'EA',
      templateUrl: 'queryRowTemplate.html',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.addRqst = function() {
          $scope.$emit('addRowRqst')
        };
        $scope.removeRqst = function(index) {
          $scope.$emit('removeRowRqst', index)
        };
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      }
    }
  });
```

The relevant snippet of HTML

```
....
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="removeRqst($parent.row)" type="submit">Delete Row</button>
....
```

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/rDkXpIgiOSoNvLNPsVbP

Test: Click on Add Row 3 times. Then click on Delete on second row. You will see that it actually removes the 3 row, not 2nd

Comment: Your plunker seems to be working fine. How do you check which item gets removed? Please be aware that you didn't bind the inputs to the objects.

Comment: See my Test comment above. The problem is not removing. The problem is removing the correct one

Comment: Plunker to be more clear: http://plnkr.co/edit/IZN3XJMpJMyhrw1sEgOk It works fine.

Comment: It is always deleting the *last* row

Comment: Right, and I don't want it to always delete last row. I want it to delete the specific row that I click on Delete button

Comment: What is args?  Are you sure that the indexOf is finding it and not returning -1?  How is it invoked?  'removeRqst' != 'removeRowRqst'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear with the answer @ZsoltGyöngyösi gave:

> Every element with and `id` field needs `ng-model="$parent.row.field"`

Thus, the correct row will be deleted if you setup `queryRowTemplate.hml` this way:

#### queryRowTemplate.html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="selectedField">Select Field</label>
  <select id="selectedField" class="form-control" ng-model="$parent.row.field">
    <option>title</option>
    <option>application</option>
    <option>subject</option>
    <option>filetype</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="logicalOperator">Logical Operator</label>
  <select id="logicalOperator" class="form-control" ng-model="$parent.row.logical">
    <option>equal to</option>
    <option>not equal to</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="searchText">Search</label>
  <input id="searchText" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="search..." ng-model="$parent.row.search" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="operator">Operator (optional)</label>
  <select id="operator" class="form-control" ng-model="$parent.row.operator">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>AND</option>
    <option>OR</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addRqst()" type="submit">Add Row</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="removeRqst($parent.row)" type="submit">Delete Row</button>
{{$parent.$index}}
<hr />
```

[See Plunkr, here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IZN3XJMpJMyhrw1sEgOk?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine, the correct form is being deleted. The problem is that you are not binding your view to the `queryRow` directive, so it seems that the last one is being deleted. In reality, angular rebuilds your view based on the array, not knowing about the content of the templates. Hence unbound input fields simply retain the values, except for the last one.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not quite sure I understand the part of the unbound fields retaining their values. So for example, when I didn't bind the view to model, if I put something in a text input, it still remained there. So are you saying that if I had 3 rows, with text 'abc' in the 2nd row- Angular would redraw it and put the 'abc' in 2nd row?

Comment: See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QrXMMU58IV4rJSG0T0n7?p=preview 
To verify that correct form is being deleted, however input fields are retaining values when they should not.

Comment: Now see this one http://plnkr.co/edit/dSaePFJzXnF0kl2cTsMA?p=preview 
working correctly

Comment: The issue occurs because, what you see is rendered from the parent controller, defined in your `queryBuilder`. All children views are rendered based as the array iterations. Whenever you make changes to the array, angular simply reiterates through the array and removes/inserts whatever is missing. Since there is no object reference dependency between children and parent directives, hence the last item is being removed. Hope this clears the confusion :)

Comment: and by the way my answer should be accepted instead, since it explains why the issue occurs, and not simply shows the magical fix :)