# Angularjs Splice on File type Input field always remove last element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, splice, input-type-file

Angularjs splice from an array of images for input type file always remove last element from html view -

```html
<div class="mt-1" ng-repeat="plan in data.images.Projects track by $index">
<div class="input-group">
    <span  class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="radio" name="images" ng-model="data.banner_image"
               ng-value="$index" />
    </span>
    <input type="file" file-model="data.images.Projects[$index]"
           class="form-control" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg">
    <span class="input-group-btn" ng-click="data.images.Projects.splice($index,1)">
        <button class="btn white" type="button">
            <span class="fa fa-minus-square"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: please look into this. I guess same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637512/angular-splice-function-always-removes-last-element

Comment: @AbuSufian working fine with other input types other than file type.

Comment: **Double-check that your example reproduces the problem.**